# Eclipse shows error on package but inside this package Eclipse doesn't show errors

Tags: java, eclipse

Often I have same problem
that Eclipse shows error on package but inside this package doesn't show errors.

### Demonstartion:

[image]

According the picture in package aren't classes with problems.

P.S. it is package explorer view.

I made `clean` for project and `refresh`. But it wasn't helpful.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you see anything meanfull in the markers view?

Comment: check problems window output.

Comment: could be a build path problem, the error window should tell you

Comment: Look at the Problems View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens sometimes for no apparent reason.

Since you tried to clean and rebuild the project, just check out the Problems-tab where you can see the error message. Can be found at:

```
Window -> Show View -> Problems
```

Maybe there's something that will give you a hint how to solve the problem.

Comment: Really. I see problems there but strange that don't see it in package explorer. it is very uncomfortable to search problems in huge project by this way.

Comment: I just tried to help you but I hope you will solve your problem and maybe you could post the solution here for other users to know where this error comes from.

Comment: it is not solution. I just see cause of problem in Problems view but doesn't see in package explorer. I think it is Eclipse bug.